# SASS evaluates E notation when interpolating certain map keys

Tags: css, ruby, sass, interpolation

Scenario: Ruby v2.2.4p230, Sass v3.4.22, Windows 10 v1511. See snippet below. Also occurs using http://www.sassmeister.com/, so it does not appear to be a local machine issue.

Problem: When compiled, certain keys are interpolated with values that are similar but appear corrupt, with numerous zeros inserted.

These are sample key values that are problematic and the associated value that is interpolated:

- 270e00 => 270
- 270e0f => 270f
- 270e10 => 2700000000000
- 270e90 => 270000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
- 270e9e => 270000000000e
- 270e9f => 270000000000f

Through trying other values, the issue seems occurs when the key starts with one or more numeric characters followed by the character 'e' and then one or more numeric characters. Any letters after that are printed normally. All the other values are interpolated without issue.

Based on this, it appears that Sass is evaluating a key starting with #e# as if it were in [E notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation).

```css
$imagePath: '../img/';
$images: (
 contact: (
  elements: (email, phone, linkedin, twitter),
  colors: (
   fff: (states: 1, sizes: (22, 24,26)),
   782bbb: (states: 2, sizes: 26),
  )
 ),
 page-front: (
  elements: (cloud, computer, phone, printer, server),
  colors: (
   270dff: (states: 1, sizes: 64),
   270e00: (states: 1, sizes: 64),
   270e0f: (states: 1, sizes: 64),
   270e10: (states: 1, sizes: 64),
   270e90: (states: 1, sizes: 64),
   270e9e: (states: 1, sizes: 64),
   270e9f: (states: 1, sizes: 64),
   270ea0: (states: 1, sizes: 64),
   270ef0: (states: 1, sizes: 64),
   270f00: (states: 1, sizes: 64),
   e9aea0: (states: 1, sizes: 64)
  )
 ),
);
@each $type, $type-values in $images {
 @each $color, $color-values in map-get($type-values, colors) {

  @each $size in map-get($color-values, sizes) {
   .icon-type-#{$type} {
    &.icon-color-#{$color}, .icon-color-#{$color} {
     &.icon-size-#{$size}, .icon-size-#{$size} {
      &.icon, .icon {
       .image {

        height: #{$size}px;
        background-image: url(#{$imagePath}#{$type}-#{$color}-#{$size}.png);

        &.alt-hidden {
         width: #{$size}px;
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }

  $elements: map-get($type-values, elements);

  @for $i from 1 through length($elements) {

   $posY: (($i - 1)/(length($elements) - 1))*100%;

   .icon-type-#{$type} {
    &.icon-color-#{$color}, .icon-color-#{$color} {
     &.icon, .icon {
      &.#{nth($elements, $i)} {

       .image { background-position: 0 $posY; }

       @if map-get($color-values, states) > 1 {

        &:active {
         .image { background-position: 100% $posY; }
        }

        $posX: 100%;

        @if map-get($color-values, states) == 3 { $posX: 50%; }

        &:hover, &:focus{
         .image { background-position: $posX $posY; }
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be resolved by enclosing the key in single or double quotes.